# Sending body via POST on redirect

Tags: android, networking, retrofit

I have an established code base which successfully makes GET and POST requests to a server to download/upload data. We're looking to change the domain name and have set up a 301 HTTP redirect to go from the original domain to the new domain. When doing a GET request, it seems to automatically handle the redirect in the background and successfully retrieves the response. When I am sending a body via POST, however, it throws a java.net.ProtocolException: content-length promised xx bytes, but received 0.

Is there any way to ensure that the body is sent in the redirect request as well? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: No we ended up leaving both URLs alive for the update period and then changing it to a 301 again after a decent period of time for app updates